Shift tab isn't showing docstring anymore
I did a clean install of Ubuntu 23 and Jupyter Lab 4.2.0.
Previously when I created a notebook with, say, pd.read_csv() put my cursor between the brackets and pressed shift+tab a docstring would immediately appear.
Now it doesn't appear at all.
How do I fix it?
?pd.read_csv does work, but is extremely inconvenient compared to shift+tab.

Does the auto-completer prompt you with options below if you start writing pd.read_c and wait or hit tab?

I can repro, I opened https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/16319

@Wayne , yes, when I print this part and hit tab, I get a dropdown menu of sorts with possible continuations. The one you'd expect to see. This part works properly.

This user reported downgrading to JupyterLab 4.1.8 helped. If you are using Anaconada/conda, do it through there and not the pip install suggested there. Or at least try the correct way first. For others ending up here, sometimes timing is important to getting this to work, see here.

This was fixed in JupyterLab 4.2.1 which was released on 2024-05-03. The solution is to upgrade JupyterLab.
